Custom Key Signatures in Sibelius Ultimate
I am looking for a way to notate Byzantine scales in Sibelius.  I've decided on the symbols I want in the key signature.  Is there a way to generate a custom key signature in Sibelius?  I would also like to use this for the D double harmonic minor scale, which is also a Byzantine tone (Bb, Eb, F#, and C#).

As Laurence answered Sibelius does not do this, which means you’ll have to manually draw in these symbols (and then take care of accidental rules). Is there any reason you want to do it in exactly Sibelius? All common alternatives (even ones like MuseScore) do offer proper support for this, so to me it seems like here Sibelius is not the software of choice.

No.  You'll have to fake it with symbols.
Here's a couple of suggestions how.
link to Sibelius forum

This would be a stronger answer if it included instructions on how to fake it with symbols.
